# SAP equivalent of IsMSShipped (ie, is a system object)

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

I want to know how to determine if a object (eg, a view) is a system object or a user object. Is this possible?

I'm using SAP ASE 16.0.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, system objects are those with their sysobjects.id < 256. These are mostly only system tables that are predefined and cannot be influenced by the DBA. These have sysobjects.type ='S'.

This does not include 'system' views (like sysquerymetrics) and system stored procs, like sp_help etc., these are really created afterwards when the installmaster script (and its cousins) is run, and these will therefore have an object ID > 255 and object type <> 'S'.

Nothing stops you from creating your own 'sp_' procedures in sybsystemprocs (and there are many good reasons to do so), so you cannot judge by the 'sp_' prefix whether something is a system stored proc or not.

So basically, there is no water-tight way to test this for anything except the real system tables. You could of course build your own function to check this, which could include a list of all procedures created by the installmaster script, but that sounds like a pretty heavy solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can check `sysobjects` for type = "U" for user objects, or type = "S" for system objects.

```
select name, type from sysobjects
where type = "U"

select name, type from sysobjects
where type = "S"
```

The other typical values for `type` are: 
`U`= User Object
`S`= System Object
`RI` = Constraint
`D`= Default
`R`= Rule
`TR`= Trigger
`P`= Procedure

For views and other non-table objects (except procedures), SAP ASE uses `sys` to prefix the names.  For procedures, SAP ASE prefixes them with `sp_` or `mon_` and you'll want to check to see if it exists in `sybsystemprocs` or `master` to determine if it's a system procedure.

Comment: If I wanted to get all the user-created views, is my only option to get all those where " where type = 'V' ", exclude those prefixed with "sys" and hope no-one has created a view prefixed with "sys" ?

Comment: Unfortunately that is the case.